# How to show the jbutton that are inserted in a subpanel inside the mainpanel?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I cant seem to get it right. The code doesn't have any syntax error but it does not display what I want to display. Here are the codes that I've written. Thank you in advance for helping. I wanted to display image jbuttons in gamepanel(subpanel).. there should be 9 jbuttons there but it doesn't show. the frame is just gray. I don't know how to let the subpanel display.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class midterm extends JFrame
{
    JPanel mainpanel;
    JButton image1=new JButton();
    JButton image2=new JButton();
    JButton image3=new JButton();
    JButton image4=new JButton();
    JButton image5=new JButton();
    JButton image6=new JButton();
    JButton image7=new JButton();
    JButton image8=new JButton();
    JButton image9=new JButton();   


    JLabel text=new JLabel("Please select a photo above.");


    public midterm()
    {
        super("Girls' Generation - I GOT A BOY 4th Korean Album");
        setSize(700,700);
        setLocation(200,30);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);

        panel();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        midterm frame=new midterm();
    }

    void panel()
    {
        mainpanel=new JPanel();
        mainpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        JPanel gamepanel=new JPanel();
        gamepanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Photo Puzzle"));
        gamepanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));


        ImageIcon sica = new ImageIcon("jung.jpg");
        image1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
        image1.setIcon(sica);
        image1.setSize(200,200);
        image1.setVisible(true);
        image1.setToolTipText("Jessica Jung Sooyeon");
        gamepanel.add((image1));

        ImageIcon yuri = new ImageIcon("kwon.jpg");
        image2.setIcon(yuri);
        image2.setSize(200,200);
        image2.setVisible(true);
        image2.setToolTipText("Kwon Yuri");
        gamepanel.add(image2);

        ImageIcon tiff = new ImageIcon("hwang.jpg");
        image3.setIcon(tiff);
        image3.setSize(200,200);
        image3.setVisible(true);
        image3.setToolTipText("Tiffany Hwang Miyoung");
        gamepanel.add(image3);

        ImageIcon sunny = new ImageIcon("lee.jpg");
        image4.setIcon(sunny);
        image4.setSize(200,200);
        image4.setVisible(true);
        image4.setToolTipText("Sunny Lee Sunkyu");      
        gamepanel.add(image4);

        ImageIcon soo = new ImageIcon("choi.jpg");
        image5.setIcon(soo);
        image5.setSize(200,200);
        image5.setVisible(true);
        image5.setToolTipText("Choi Sooyoung");
        gamepanel.add(image5);

        ImageIcon hyo = new ImageIcon("kimh.jpg");
        image6.setIcon(hyo);
        image6.setSize(200,200);
        image6.setVisible(true);
        image6.setToolTipText("Kim Hyoyeon");
        gamepanel.add(image6);

        ImageIcon yoona = new ImageIcon("im.jpg");
        image7.setIcon(yoona);
        image7.setSize(200,200);
        image7.setVisible(true);
        image7.setToolTipText("Im Yoona");      
        gamepanel.add(image7);

        ImageIcon taeng = new ImageIcon("kimt.jpg");
        image8.setIcon(taeng);
        image8.setSize(200,200);
        image8.setVisible(true);
        image8.setToolTipText("Kim Taeyeon");
        gamepanel.add(image8);

        ImageIcon hyunnie = new ImageIcon("seo.jpg");
        image9.setIcon(hyunnie);
        image9.setSize(200,200);
        image9.setVisible(true);
        image9.setToolTipText("Seohyun Seo Juhyun");
        gamepanel.add(image9);



        JPanel controls = new JPanel();
        controls.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        controls.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Control"));

        JButton newGame = new JButton("New Game");
        controls.add(newGame, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JButton exitGame = new JButton("Exit");
        controls.add(exitGame, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        mainpanel.add(gamepanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainpanel.add(controls, BorderLayout.EAST);


        process jj = new process(); 

        image1.addActionListener(jj);
        image2.addActionListener(jj);
        image3.addActionListener(jj);
        image4.addActionListener(jj);
        image5.addActionListener(jj);
        image6.addActionListener(jj);
        image7.addActionListener(jj);
        image8.addActionListener(jj);
        image9.addActionListener(jj);


    }

    class process implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource().equals(image1))
            {
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image2))
            {
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image3))
            {
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image4))
            {
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image5))
            {
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image6))
            {
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image7))
            {
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image8))
            {
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image9))
            {
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image1.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

            }

        }
    }






}
```

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot would've helped.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is you are not adding your display panel to the `JFrame`.

With `Swing` you need to add it to the `content pane`.

After that you want to call `pack()` this will resize the pane and make everything in it "fit".

Calling `setVisible(true)` last is not necessary, but is good practice.

I have always found the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) helpful.

```
public midterm()
{
    super("Girls' Generation - I GOT A BOY 4th Korean Album");
    setSize(700,700);
    setLocation(200,30);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    panel();
    this.getContentPane().add(mainpanel);//<-- add panel to content pane
    this.pack();                         //<-- resize everything
    setVisible(true);                    //<-- display
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! It worked! :) I'm a beginner and thank you thank you.. I'm trying to build a picture puzzle and I'm still searching on how to do it.. :) anyway, this is a great help.. again, thank you

Comment: @arnelyn Care to accept the answer that helped you the most ;)

Answer (score 2):

You never add `mainpanel` to your `JFrame`. Also make sure that you call `JFrame.setVisible(true)` *after* adding all components.

Answer (score 0):

just add Jpanel (**mainpanel** ) to your Jframe

```
panel();    
this.getContentPane().add(mainpanel);
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: `show` is deprecated and my be removed in future releases, you should be using `setVisible(true)` instead...